# Format Result of VBA code respective to row

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I have below sheet

[image]

I am using below code to get reports in different sheet for Blank cells which

```
Sub Loop_Column_Row()
    
    Dim lRow, lCol As Long

    'Counter
    Dim i As Integer
    'Find the last non-blank cell in row 1
    'This assumes that the first 5 row has column headers
    lCol = Cells(6, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    i = 1
    
    'Loop through columns
    For x = 1 To lCol
        'Find the last non-blank cell in the column
        lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, x).End(xlUp).Row
    
        'Loop through rows
        'Start from row 2 as row 1 is the row with headers
        For y = 6 To lRow
            If Cells(y, x) = "" Then
                'Write in column A of Sheet3
                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ReportEmptyCell").Range("A" & i).Value = "Cell in Row: " & y & " Column: " & x & " is empty"
                i = i + 1
            End If
        Next y
    Next x
  
End Sub
```

return my result in particular format

[image]

I want to modify this code so empty rows get  red and end result should be like below repect to Col3 as Col3 will never be empty

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why do you need to use VBA for this? Red colouring can be done easily using conditional formatting. A simple formula can give you your col1,col2 text e.g. `=IF(ISBLANK(A2),"Col1, ","")&IF(ISBLANK(B2),"Col2","")`

Comment: how can i desired result in format

Comment: Conditional formatting is a built-in feature of Excel found on the Home ribbon. You can make a new rule that says if the cell is blank, then colour it red. Your format will then be as desired.